# Gparted -Ubuntu Is Using all of my disk and will not allow resizing. For Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I recently installed Ubuntu, I have it for Dual Boot. Windows is already installed on a different Drive.
For install, I used the whole disk and wiped it thinking I would be able to resize the main partition so I could create a new partition for extra space for Extra space. However, [Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O13qI.png) in Gparted does not allow Resizing and remains with Keys image in front of the Ext4 partition.
It is only using 24.55GiB of 906Gib. 
I have in the image linked turned off swap.

Comment: A better solution would have been to do manual partitioning and leave some space for Windows but the recommended way is to install windows first then Ubuntu. So it ought to have been the other way round!

Comment: George Udosen. I forgot to include Windows is already installed on a different Disk

Comment: I don't know if it relates to my issue. Thanks though. I'm not very good with Partitioning.

Comment: You didn't use a logical partition did you?

Comment: The little key icon shows partition is mounted. So you cannot use gparted from a mounted  Ubuntu partition. See comments & answer on using live installer in live mode or gparted live system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried repartitioning using a Gparted live USB? I have had issues resizing active partitions in the past but using a live USB has always worked for me.

Comment: Correct. You CANNOT resize a mounted partition. Doing so will cause data loss, so Linux partition-editing applications will refuse to operate on mounted partitions. Boot from a LiveUSB so your system partition is not mounted. WARNING: Partitioning operations are *inherently risky* - whle Linux developers have worked very hard to make partitioning tools as safe as possible, proper backups of all the data that you value are strongly encouraged before you begin editing partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I figured as much but can never be sure with the complexity of things and breakthroughs in workflows and stuff. Speaking of, do you know if there's any way baked into Ubuntu to go into a partition management pre-boot environment and mess with partitions there? I mean I suppose if you had separate partitions instead of a simple install you could just unmount the non-critical directories and repartition that way.

Comment: Well, the partitioning application needs to run on top of an Operating System, and that OS needs to boot.